# Continuous third party APIs monitoring & testing on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

We would like to setup automated jobs (via `Jenkins`) to alert if the third party API is down or they deployed an incompatible APIs.

I am talking about to test against the real `HTTP APIs` and not a mock, but as we already have mock written using `rspec`, I am not sure if we should duplicate the effort by writing two independent testes.

Anyone have this experience in this before? 
(I am not limited to `Ruby/Rspec` if other tools can help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocks are used to test **YOUR OWN** code w/o touching real API. And you want to test real API.

So I think you have to write a set of tests in RSpec for example for **unobtrusive** test of 3rd party API.
By "unobtrusive" I mean track than you don't issue accidental "DELETE" API requests for example, or use all your daily requests API limit by a single test suite run.

Don't know if specified API test tools exist.
As for me, I used RSpec to test my own remote APIs/servers with success.

Answer (score 5):

Have you had a look at [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr)?  Using it, you can "record your test suite's HTTP interactions and replay them during future test runs for fast, deterministic, accurate tests".  I've used it with RSpec when testing expected responses from external APIs, and think it's great.  I'd encourage you to check out the StackOverflow questions tagged with [vcr](/questions/tagged/vcr) if it's something you think may work for you.

Not sure of its Jenkins integration, but when I was using VCR, I automated some regular tasks where I needed to hit the APIs with [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) ("Cron jobs in Ruby").  Not really continuous, but somewhat automated.

Comment: I agree, VCR is great for this. Essentially recording a "Contract" of sorts. You can then re-record and check the differences.

Answer (score 4):

When I was in this situation a few months ago I did the following:

1. Mock the API and write tests against the mocked data (you already have that)
2. Write one more test that gets data from the real API and asserts that it is (still) in the same form and contains the same kind of data that we expect

I did it like this since it was impossible for me to guess/know what content will be provided by the live API.

Comment: That's what we have done in the past. You can schedule the Jenkins job that checks that you can still interact with the 3rd party API nightly or weekly and it will notify you of changes to the dependent API.

Comment: One more thing... As a service that others depend on, we've gone so far as encourage this, and set up an e-mail account that, when a client's build fails because of our API changes, they can notify us through their automated test. This way we know when we've negatively impacted our clients.

Comment: I recently found the Weary gem https://github.com/mwunsch/weary which seems a great way to "wrap" your access to any API and write fairly simple tests (see Gilt https://github.com/mwunsch/gilt)

Comment: @bcarlso nice tip about the email from the client's tests.

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 things I'd do to the existing test suite so it could be used live, the first uses the  ability for `describe` and `it` blocks to take metadata ([There's a good blog post on it here](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/06/14/filtering-examples-in-rspec-2/)). The second uses the ability for `shared_contexts` to take a block.

Firstly, mark the specs you'd like to run against the real API with metadata. For example, you want to know these can be run for real, e.g.

```
describe "Hitting the API with a call", :can_be_real do
  # …
end
```

These specs can then be run from the commandline [using the tag option](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-12/docs/command-line/tag-option).

The second thing, is to replace the mocks with the real thing. It depends on how you've defined the mocks, whether a `before` or a `let` was used, and how much you mocked. As a silly example, see below:

```
require 'rspec'

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
end

shared_context "all my mocks and stubs" do
  let(:this) { false }
end

describe "a", :real do
  include_context "all my mocks and stubs" do
    let(:this) { true } if ENV["REAL_API_CALL"] == 'true'
    before do
      stub_const( "URI", Class.new ) unless ENV["REAL_API_CALL"] == 'true'
    end
  end
  it "should be real when it's real" do
    this.should == true
  end
  it "should escape things when it's real" do
    URI.should respond_to :escape
  end
end
```

When the file is run via `bin/rspec example.rb` the output is:

```
a
  should be real when it's real (FAILED - 1)
  should escape things when it's real (FAILED - 2)

Failures:

  1) a should be real when it's real
     Failure/Error: this.should == true
       expected: true
            got: false (using ==)
     # ./example.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) a should escape things when it's real
     Failure/Error: URI.should respond_to :escape
       expected URI to respond to :escape
     # ./example.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00349 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures
```

When run via `env REAL_API_CALL=true bin/rspec example.rb`:

```
a
  should be real when it's real
  should escape things when it's real

Finished in 0.00301 seconds
2 examples, 0 failures
```

So you see, you can change the context of the specs in several ways that would allow you the level of control you want from the command line (and hence, Jenkins). You would want to mark the specs with other metadata, such as whether it's safe to run for real, whether it may take a long time etc.